# VBA cannot open XML file from URL, but can process the same file if downloaded

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I've had a piece of VBA code that has been working flawlessly for 5 years that stopped working yesterday.  It's a simple retrieval of an XML file from a URL, which is then parsed and used.

Original Code:

```
Dim objXML as Object
Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
objXML.async = False: objXML.validateOnParse = False
objXML.LoadXML ("https://www.myurl.com/webservicehttp.aspx?key=mykey&format=xml")
```

The following error occurs when the macro reaches the "LoadXML" line:
[image]

I don't think it's a network access issue because when I load the same URL in a browser, I can view the XML document.  I'm also able to load JSON files from the same server using the same account.

I'm almost positive it's not an issue with the XML because when I download the file, I can load it from a local directory:
`objXML.LoadXML ("C:\MyFolder\downloadedxml.xml")`

I've tried using the URL encoding function with no change:

```
Const strURL as String = "https://www.myurl.com/webservicehttp.aspx?key=mykey&format=xml"
Dim encodedURL As String
encodedURL = WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(strURL)
Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
objXML.async = False: objXML.validateOnParse = False
objXML.LoadXML (encodedURL)
```

In researching online, I came across this slightly different method, which resulted in the same error when it reaches the .LoadFromFile line:

```
Dim objDom As Object, strData As String, objStream As ADODB.Stream
Set objDom = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")
Set objStream = New ADODB.Stream 
With objStream
    .Charset = "UTF-8"
    .Open
    .LoadFromFile (encodedURL)
End With
```

I've checked with the service provider, and there's been no API or security changes on their end.

That's the point I'm at right now.  Appreciate any insight or assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `ServerHTTPRequest` property to `True`. It is `False` by default.

[ServerHTTPRequest Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms766434(v=vs.85))

> Specifies whether to enable (true) or disable (false) the use of the ServerHTTPRequest object in a server application. Setting the property to false causes the DOM object not to use the HTTPRequest object. Setting this property to true causes DOM documents to use ServerHTTPRequest.

> This property is supported in MSXML 3.0 and 6.0. **The default value is false.**

Add the following line immediately following the line: `objXML.async = False`:

```
objXML.setProperty("ServerHTTPRequest", true)
```

Comment: Well shut my mouth and paint me red.  That did it.  I've now got a new issue in that after loading the XML, it's giving me an "Invalid at top level" error, but at least it's loading now.

Any idea why it would have worked for so long without that line and then suddenly stop working?